# Exporting .avi video to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, transparency, alpha, avi

I'm making an application with two windows, one a windows form that serves as a controller and the other an instance of unity that renders what the form says. Well the problem I have is when using videos with transparent backgrounds in .avi format. What I want to do is to send the address of the file to unity, which I have already achieved with the url of the videoPlayer, but the Alpha channel does not work.

I tried cheking with DiVinciResolve if the video has transparency, it does. I also tried adding diferent materials.

Comment: Did you enable "Keep Alpha" on the video?

Comment: When I see the video in the inspector it shows the option keep alpha but it does not let me enable it.

Comment: Then it did not "recognize" the Alpha channel in the video. Have you tried using other formats? Like mov?

Comment: Yhea I tried using every format and coder I could posible think of. But any of them worked. I am thinking about loading every frame of the video in a Texture2D to keep the alpha chanel, any idea?

Comment: To be honest, that is what I did when I failed and I was gonna suggest it. To reduce the workload, you can make use of the Animator. That will drop over 60% of the work you'd normally have to do by manually adjusting frames in code and takes 3 seconds to set up a full clip automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you have any code on how you have done the implementation?

Comment: I assume you were initially planning a RenderTexture content replication to a RawImage on the Canvas using the avi, correct? Just to make sure you have the same context as I did.

Comment: Exactly that is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I alredy found the answer. You have to use a tool like FFmpeg to convert the video into a row of images an then load the images in order in Unity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).